# add rows to groups in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

I've got a pandas dataframe `df`. Created like this:

```
a = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2]).T

bcd = np.array([np.arange(1,10)]*3).T

df = pd.DataFrame(bcd, columns=["b","c","d"])

df["a"] = a
```

Looks like this:

```
     b   c   d   a
0    1   1   1   0
1    2   2   2   0
2    3   3   3   0
3    4   4   4   1
4    5   5   5   1
5    6   6   6   1
6    7   7   7   2
7    8   8   8   2
8    9   9   9   2
```

I would like to insert 3 rows after each grouping in column `'a'`. Specifically, I want to have some auto-incrementation in column `'b'` and put `None` objects everywhere else: Something like:

```
     b   c    d    a 
0    1   1    1    0
1    2   2    2    0
2    3   3    3    0
3    10  None None 0
4    11  None None 0
5    12  None None 0
6    4   4    4    1
7    5   5    5    1
8    6   6    6    1
9    10  None None 1
10   11  None None 1
11   12  None None 1
12   7   7    7    2
13   8   8    8    2
14   9   9    9    2
15   10  None None 2
16   11  None None 2
17   12  None None 2
```

Comment: You want to have duplicate index 3, 4 and 5?

Comment: lol no sorry, typo. I wrote that out by hand. Fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is not really an insert operation, as the data structure behind the `DataFrame` does not allow simple inserting. So, in essence, you will have to build a new `DataFrame` from the pieces of your old `DataFrame`.

So, your code should:

1. Create a new `DataFrame`
2. Find where to split the table (by using column `a`)
3. Append the slice from the existing table to the new `DataFrame`
4. Create new bits of data
5. Append the new data to the new `DataFrame`
6. Repeat steps 2-5 as many times as required.

(Or you can concatenate instead of append, if you find it easier.) One thing to think of is what you do with your indices. If you do not use them, you may ignore them (= create new as needed) by using the `ignore_index=True` keyword argument on `concat` or `append`.

For more information:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html

BTW, you do not necessarily want to have any `None`s in your dataframe. If you have numerical data, you want to have `NaN` instead. Otherwise strange things may happen (you end up with object arrays). See:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

Answer (score 3):

Just `concat` the inserts that you want to insert in (and they will be appended in the rear, or `df.append(the_insert)`, which does the same thing) and `reset_index` the resultant to get things in the right order:

```
In [137]:

df2=pd.DataFrame({'b':[11,12,13], 'a':[0]*3})
In [138]:

df3=pd.concat((df, df2)).sort('a').reset_index(drop=True)
#pd.concat((df, df2, df3, df4...., all the others...))
In [139]:

print df3
    a   b   c   d
0   0   1   1   1
1   0   2   2   2
2   0   3   3   3
3   0  11 NaN NaN
4   0  12 NaN NaN
5   0  13 NaN NaN
6   1   4   4   4
7   1   5   5   5
8   1   6   6   6
9   2   7   7   7
10  2   8   8   8
11  2   9   9   9
```